# Can't create controller properly with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco

So here is a quick overview. I'm using Code First, new database.

[image: Overview]

As you'll see I have created a AccountModels model (same name as default in case anyone is confused). It looks like the following:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Stat> Stats { get; set; }
}

public class Stat
{
    public int StatId { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class BodylogDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stat> Stats { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BodylogDbContext>(null);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Now when I'm trying to add a Controller I can't choose my model class, AccountModel. As I remember, I should be able to choose the model class and then in the next field I choose my data context class which is - BodylogDbContext (Bodylog.Models) and everything should be set. But I can't, why?

[image: Create controller]

And here is my connection string.

```
   <add name="BodylogDbContext"
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Bodylog.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

Comment: looks fine to me.  `AccountModels` looks like it is just the name of the file not the class.  The drop down will show you the public class names.  `Stat` and `User` are there.  What are you expecting to be in the drop down?

Comment: I was thinking it should show AccountModels? It seems wrong to me that I have to choose `User` or `Stat` since they're _the same_ if you know what I mean? ehh :/

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"?  Sorry, I don't exactly know what you mean. ;)  The physical file that you place your classes in has nothing to do with how the code is compiled.  In this case, after compilation, c# has no knowledge of your AccountModels.cs file.  The drop down list is showing a reflected view of the compiled assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as expected here.  One of the problems here is that in the sample project, a file called AccountModels.cs is provided containing multiple model classes.  Convention dictates that these actually be split out into multiple files, one file per class, and named after the class.

There is no class called AccountModels in your project, which is why it's not being presented as an option for a model.

Comment: The thing that creates a fuzz in my head is that `Stat` is supposed to be a _part_ of a `User`. So if I use EF to create CRUD operations for me it won't include `Stat`'s. I thought I was following convention when I named the class AccountModels then later to create the Controller `AccountController`, which irritates me because then I can only choose `User`or `Stat`and not AccountModels class.

Answer (score 0):

Having a `.cs` file does not create an "implied" class. You'll only see types that have concrete definitions in the dropdown. So, if you wanted to have a parent class of `AccountModel` (where all the other POCOs define properties of that model), you'll need something like:

```
public class AccountModel
{
    public User UserModel { get; set; }
    public Stat StatModel { get; set; }
}
```

So your Razor model binding would look similar to:

`@model Your.Fully.Qualified.Namespace.AccountModel`

You would bind to the model's User properties like this:

`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserModel.Email)`

Comment: @twice `AccountModel` would not be an EF class - it's sole purpose to transport the `User` and `Stat` classes together so that the model binding has a concrete class to work with. Although, now that I actually look a little closer, your `User` class actually contains a child collection of `Stat` objects. Are you just trying to create a "user edit" view?

Comment: Yes, `User` has a child entity, `Stat`. When I let EF create CRUD operations for `User`. I'll be navigating to **localhost:12345/Account/Create** and it'll list the respected properties from `User`, _Username_, _Password_ and _Email_ however I'd like to have EF include the Stats also. Though I assume I would be able to add them there manually somehow in the View files.

**EDIT:** Would you also happen to know if the _virtual_ keyword is necessary in this line? `Stat` - `public virtual User User { get; set; }`